# jquery on each bind text for parent attribute name values

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do my own tooltip, which should show the value of parent element name value:

I am appending new div after my anchor tag, and try to bind the text value of parent anchor name value...

But i am getting only the last name value(tooltip 3333333333333) in all my (.tooltipContainer)  div ? can any one help to resolve?

```
HTML:
            <!-- tooltip - begin  -->
            <ul>
                <li><a name="tooltip 1111111111111" class="customToolTip">tool tip 1111</a></li>
                <li><a name="tooltip 2222222222222" class="customToolTip">tool tip 222</a></li>
                <li><a name="tooltip 3333333333333" class="customToolTip">tool tip 333333</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- tooltip  end  -->  

    JS:
    $(document).ready( function() { 
        $(".customToolTip").each(function(i){
            var customToolTipName = $(this).attr('name');
            var parentAttrNameValue = $(this).parent().find(".customToolTip").attr('name');
        //  alert(parentAttrNameValue);

            $(this).after('<div class="tooltipContainer"></div>');
            $(".tooltipContainer").html(parentAttrNameValue);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `$(".tooltipContainer")` which gets all the elements with class `tooltipContainer` instead of the just added one and sets its html as `parentAttrNameValue` value, so when the last item is processed its value is set for all the elements.

Instead you can add the element as given below, here we set the html for the new element when it is being created.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".customToolTip").each(function (i) {
        var customToolTipName = $(this).attr('name');
        var parentAttrNameValue = $(this).parent().find(".customToolTip").attr('name');
        //  alert(parentAttrNameValue);

        $('<div />', {
            html: parentAttrNameValue, 'class': 'tooltipContainer'
        }).insertAfter(this);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g8b9ef50/)

Also not sure what is `parentAttrNameValue`, it is the same as `customToolTipName`

Comment: ya parentAttrNameValue and customToolTipName are same... thanks for your code... how to keep this as method.. so that we can use for any project ?